# $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{D}$ and doesn't have zero points, then $\exists g$ on $\mathbb{D}$ s.t. $\forall x\in(-1,1), g(x)=|f(x)|$

Tags: complex-analysis, radicals, analytic-functions

**Problem:**

Prove that if $f(z)$ is analytic on $\mathbb{D}$ and doesn't have zero points, then $\exists g(z)$ (which is also analytic) on $\mathbb{D}$, s.t. $\forall x\in(-1,1), g(x)=|f(x)|$. Here $\mathbb{D}$ is the unit disk.

**My attempt:**

Let $g(z)=\sqrt{f(z)\overline{f(\bar{z})}}$. Obviously $\forall x\in(-1,1), g(x)=|f(x)|$.

What I need to do is to prove $\sqrt{f(z)\overline{f(\bar{z})}}$ can get a single valued holomorphic branch. But I don't know how to prove it. Can you give some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{D}$ is a simply connected domain, even a convex one. So every holomorphic function in $\mathbb{D}$ has a primitive. So now assume $f$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}$ without zeros. Then $\frac{f'}{f}$ is holomorphic as well and so has a primitive. It's not difficult to prove that this primitive has to be a branch of $\log(f)$. And a branch of $\log(f)$ gives a branch of $\sqrt{f}$, just define $\sqrt{f}=e^{\frac{1}{2}\log(f)}$.

So now use it in your exercise. The function $f(z)\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}$ and has no zeros.

Comment: Thank you! Your proof almost also answers my other question that does every analytic function (which doesn't have zeros) defined on a simply connected area have an single valued analytic square root.

Answer (score 1):

The map $g(z)=f(z)\overline{f\left(\overline z\right)}$ is analytic and $\mathbb D$ is simply connected. Therefore, $g$ as an analytic square root in $\mathbb D$.

Since $f$ has no zeros, then neither has $g$. So, since $g(x)\in\mathbb R$ for each $x\in(-1,1)$ and $g$ is continuous, then you either always have $g(x)>0$ or you always have $g(x)<0$. Then $g$ is an answer to your problem in the first case; otherwise, take $-g$ instead.

Comment: If $h$ is an analytic square root then I can see that $h(x)^{2}=|f(x)|^{2}$ but I cannot see why $h(x)=|f(x)|$ May be I am missing something trivial.

Comment: Got it. $h(x)=\pm \sqrt {|f(x)|}$. $f$ has no zeros and the $\pm$ sign is a constant. So either $h$ or $-h$ does the job.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question. You saved me time!

Comment: You might wish to append to the answer the hypothesis that $g$ does not vanish anywhere (as written, one could assume that being analytic on a simply connected domain is sufficient for your conclusion) and the connectivity argument required to conclude that either $h$ or $-h$ will solve the problem. Namely, $h/|f|$ is continuous on $(-1,1)$ and has image on $\{-1,1\}$ etc. Just saying $h=\pm\sqrt{|f|^2}$ and "the sign is a constant" is begging the question.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Does every analytic function (which doesn't have zeros) defined on a simply connected area have an analytic square root?

Comment: Well, I mean, is it single valued?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: As for as I am concerned, *every* function is single valued.

Comment: Do you want a proof?

Comment: I'll appreciate it if you can give me a proof! Just general idea is okay.

Comment: I've got some idea in the other answer. We just need to prove Log(f) can do that.

Comment: If $f$ has no zeros, $\frac{f'}f$ is analytic and its domain is still $U$. Since $U$ is simply connected, it has a primitive in $U$, which is analytic. Fix $z_0\in U$ and let $\omega$ be a logarithm of $f(z_0)$. Then the primititive $L$ of $\frac{f'}f$ such that $L(z_0)=\omega$ is a logarithm of $f$. But then$$\left(\exp\left(\frac12L(z)\right)\right)^2=\exp\bigl(L(z)\bigr)=f(z).$$So, $\exp\left(\frac12L(z)\right)$ is an analytic square root of $f(z)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for sparing time to solve my problem! :-)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.